# How to run time.sleep() without stopping while loop

Tags: python-3.x, async-await, parallel-processing, opencv, python

Is there a way to call a function which has wait(time.sleep()) from infinite while loop without disturbing the loop?
I am trying to run a few task that require to wait for a few seconds but the issue is that the while loop also stops when the wait process is happening.
This is what I have tried out-
Here is my code:

```
import cv2
import time

def waiting():
    print("Inside function")
    # Running Some Tasks
    time.sleep(5)
    print("Done sleeping")


def main():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        cv2.imshow("Webcam", frame)

        k = cv2.waitKey(10)
        if k == 32:  # Press SPACEBAR for wait function
            waiting()
        elif k == 27:  # Press ESC to stop code
            break
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the quick responses from @JLT and @TerePiim. Here is the updated code for anyone who might benefit from this:

```
import cv2
import time
import threading


def waiting():
    print("Inside parallel function")
    # Running some Tasks
    time.sleep(5)
    print("Done sleeping")


def main():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        cv2.imshow("Webcam", frame)
        k = cv2.waitKey(10)
        if k == 32:  # Press SPACEBAR for wait function
            t = threading.Thread(target=waiting)
            t.start()

        elif k == 27:  # Press ESC to stop code
            break
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use threads. It will look like the computer is doing them both at the same time.

```
import threading

t = threading.Thread(target=function)
t.start()
```

Comment: Sorry @cris new to this platform

Answer (score 0):

You are working in a *single thread script* at the moment. You should use [threading](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/) or [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html). This makes (it look like) multiple processes (are) active. Dependent on if you use [threading](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/) or [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I will check it out. Appreciate your time.

Comment: @git-ruthvik Let me know how it goes. Good Luck!